# WorkManager: ResolvableFuture can only be called from within the same library group prefix

Tags: android, android-workmanager

For some time in my `ListenableWorker` class I have used the following:

```
public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
    ResolvableFuture<Result> resolvableFuture = ResolvableFuture.create();
    startSomeAsyncStuff(resolvableFuture);
    return resolvableFuture;
}
```

Basically, I start some asynchronous work, passing `resolvableFuture` into that function.  When the async work is done, I call the following on that `resolvableFuture` object passed from my `ListenableWorker`:

```
resolvableFuture.set(Result.success());
```

This has worked well, and still appears to, but I'm now seeing the following lint error message against `ResolvableFuture.create()`:

> ResolvableFuture can only be called from within the same library group prefix

It still compiles, but this warning bothers me.  What is the correct way to do this now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `ResolvableFuture` at all, much less the internal version used by WorkManager.

Instead, you should be using the [AndroidX Concurrent library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/concurrent#1.0.0):

> `androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0` provides `CallbackToFutureAdapter` class, a minimalistic utility that allows to wrap callback based code and return instances of `ListenableFuture`

You'll note in the [1.0.0-beta01 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/concurrent#1.0.0-beta01) that even the AndroidX Concurrent Library has removed `ResolveableFuture` from its public API.

The [Javadoc for `CallbackToFutureAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/concurrent/futures/CallbackToFutureAdapter) has a full example of what this looks like:

```
public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
    return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture(completer -> {
         // Your method can call set() or setException() on the
         // Completer to signal completion
         startSomeAsyncStuff(completer);

         // This value is used only for debug purposes: it will be used 
         // in toString() of returned future or error cases.
         return "startSomeAsyncStuff";
    });
}
```

So you'd use [`CallbackToFutureAdapter.Completer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/concurrent/futures/CallbackToFutureAdapter.Completer) in place of a `ResolvableFuture` in your `startSomeAsyncStuff` method.

Comment: Thanks, Ian.  As usual, your answer is concise and to the point.  Hopefully this will help others making the transition too.

Comment: a related question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60467796/4070848

Comment: another related question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66176591/4070848