# WorkManager: exiting properly from startWork() without doing any work

Tags: android, android-workmanager

When my scheduled periodic work request runs, it may be the case that I don't want it to do any work at that time, and just wait for the next in the periodic series.

At present I'm handling this by setting the `Completer` to a success state and returning before firing the async work stuff, like so:

```
public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
    return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture(completer -> {
        if ( notThisTime() ) {
            completer.set(Result.success());
            return "nothing to do this time";
        }
        // the following will call completer.set(Result.success()) when it is finished...
        startSomeAsyncStuff(completer);
        return "started some async stuff";
    });
}
```

Is this how it should be done?  Or should I be running the `notThisTime()` check *before* `getFuture()` and returning a `ListenableFuture` set to a completed stated, or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way of doing things.

Unless you pull in all of Guava, the only way to create a `ListenableFuture` object is via the `CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture`, therefore you have to call that anyways to gain access to the `completer` and to call `set(Result.success())`.

Both `startWork()` and the `getFuture` lambda run on the main thread, so it is equally not safe do blocking work there, so you should make sure your `notThisTime()` is safe to run on the main thread in either place.