# WorkManager using setForegroundAsync() with ListenableWorker

Tags: android, android-workmanager

A [very useful guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running#long-running-java) and code snippet is provided for using `setForegroundAsync()` for a long-running worker in the context of a `Worker` in `WorkManager`.

What is the correct approach when using a `ListenableWorker` rather than `Worker`?  I am already using an approach based on the code snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60458030/4070848), and now want to try accessing location in the foreground as part of what is done in `startSomeAsyncStuff()` from that code snippet... based on [this part](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running#specify-foreground-service-types-runtime) of the above guide.

To modify my existing `ListenableWorker` approach, I have started with the code snippet from [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60458030/4070848), and have come up with:

```
public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
 
    String progress = "Starting Download";
    setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo(progress));

    return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture(completer -> {
        // Your method can call set() or setException() on the
        // Completer to signal completion
        download(completer, inputUrl, outputFile);

        // This value is used only for debug purposes: it will be used 
        // in toString() of returned future or error cases.
        return "downloading";
    });
}
```

The `download()` and `createForegroundInfo()` functions would be as defined in the example [from here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running#long-running-java), except that I would return from the latter with:

```
return new ForegroundInfo(0, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION);
```

Is this correct, and if not, what is?